# decorate a python function with a method from a class object

Tags: python, class, decorator

i'm looking to use a decorator on a function. the thing is the decorator function is defined inside a class and it has to be specific to an object of that class. for example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def set_a(self, val):
        self.a = val

    def bar(func):
        def _args(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs) + self.a
        return _args

if __name__ == "__main__":

    foo = Foo()
    foo2 = Foo()

    foo.set_a = 2

    @foo.bar
    def multip(a, b):
        return a * b

    multip(1, 2)  # here i would expect answer to be 4        

    foo.set_a = 3

    multip(1, 2)  # here i would expect answer to be 5

    @foo2.bar
    def multip2(a, b):
        return a * b

    multip2(1, 2)  # here i would expect the answer to be 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by "specific to an object of that class"?  What is the difference between the code you already have and the code you want to have?  (Note that you forgot the `self` argument on `bar`.)

Answer (score 0):

So you can do what you are looking for but I'm not sure I would consider this a good decorator. Why not just go for a class decorator and use `__init__()` and `__call__()`.

Anyway here's your fixed code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a

    def bar(self, func):
#           ^^^^ you need self
        def _args(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs) + self.a
#           ^^^^^^ You need to return here.
    return _args

foo = Foo()

@foo.bar
def multip(a, b):
    return a * b

multip(1, 2)
# 3
foo.a = 2
multip(1, 2)
# 4
foo.a = 3
multip(1, 2)
# 5
```